# Serialize an object to XElement and Deserialize it in memory

Tags: c#, xml, linq, serialization, c#-4.0

I want to serialize an object to XML, but I don't want to save it on the disk. I want to hold it in a XElement variable (for using with LINQ), and then Deserialize back to my object.

How can I do this?

Comment: please consider changing the accepted answer due to comment I've added to Abdul's reply. Do not make others use solution which is acceptable, - they would better use solution which is perfect (of Surjit Samra or Eren Ersönmez).

Comment: The accepted answer is not a great answer - it wastes memory allocation and assumes Ascii encoding. Eren's answer is simple, effective, and high performance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28872669/344638

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use these two extension methods to serialize and deserialize between XElement and your objects.

```
public static XElement ToXElement<T>(this object obj)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, obj);
            return XElement.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()));
        }
    }
}

public static T FromXElement<T>(this XElement xElement)
{
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xElement.CreateReader());
}
```

**USAGE**

```
XElement element = myClass.ToXElement<MyClass>();
var newMyClass = element.FromXElement<MyClass>();
```

Comment: Nice solution to create extension methods.

Comment: You should either use

public static XElement ToXElement<T>(this T obj)

Comment: @CarlSixsmith you are right - in that case specifying generic type won't be required on usage. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't `StreamWriter` default to `Encoding.UTF8`, **not** `Encoding.ASCII`? Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtbhzte9.aspx .

Comment: The perf of this approach if we first write the object to string xml and then to XElement might not be the most optimal?

Comment: You should use `Encoding.UTF8` instead of `Encoding.ASCII`.  Otherwise, if you have a string property like "На берегу пустынных волн", this will break.  Or you can by-pass explicitly using MemoryStream or Encoding (see my answer).

Comment: Not sure why this solution is so voted. First, encoding is specified for parsing, but not for writing - it's a bug since Encoding.Default may not be ASCII. Second, it's way less efficient than the answer from @Surjit Samra - you convert object > XmlDocument > string > byte[] > string > XDocument. His solution does object > XmlDocument > XDocument convertion instead. And third, making extension methods to System.Object is a really bad practice - it will add so much garbage in your intellisense everywhere!

Comment: Great answer, if someone wants to accomplish this without using generic methods consider passing .GetType() of the object as a parameter.

Comment: Consider using the T generic for the object parameter instead of "object"

Comment: This answer has good deserializing, what I was looking for. Parsing may not be optimal, but that is a different topic. For me, this answer is just as good as other answers, but perhaps not better, and perhaps not earlier. I don't mind this answer to be accepted and/or upvoted.

Answer (score 27):

You can use [XMLSerialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)

> **XML serialization is the process of converting an object's public
>   properties and fields to a serial format** (in this case, XML) for
>   storage or transport. **Deserialization re-creates the object in its
>   original state from the XML output**. You can think of serialization as
>   a way of saving the state of an object into a stream or buffer. For
>   example, ASP.NET uses the XmlSerializer class to encode XML Web
>   service messages

and [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)  `Represents an XML document` to achieve this

```
   using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
  public class Person
  {
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

      XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));

      Person p = new Person();
      p.Age = 35;
      p.Name = "Arnold";

      Console.WriteLine("\n Before serializing...\n");
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Age = {0} Name = {1}", p.Age,p.Name));

      XDocument d = new XDocument();
      using (XmlWriter xw = d.CreateWriter())
        xs.Serialize(xw, p);

      // you can use LINQ on elm now

      XElement elm = d.Root;

      Console.WriteLine("\n From XElement...\n");

      elm.Elements().All(e => { Console.WriteLine(string.Format("element name {0} , element value {1}", e.Name, e.Value)); return true; });

      //deserialize back to object
      Person pDeserialized = xs.Deserialize((d.CreateReader())) as Person;

      Console.WriteLine("\n After deserializing...\n");
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Age = {0} Name = {1}", p.Age, p.Name));

      Console.ReadLine();

    }
  }


}
```

and here is output [image]

Comment: I think you meant to write the following after the deserialization:
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Age = {0} Name = {1}", pDeserialized.Age, pDeserialized.Name));

Answer (score 21):

**(Late answer)**

Serialize:

```
var doc = new XDocument();
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
}
// now you can use `doc`(XDocument) or `doc.Root` (XElement)
```

Deserialize:

```
MyClass obj; 
using(var reader = doc.CreateReader())
{
    obj = (MyClass)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ToXelement without Code Analysis issues, same answer as Abdul Munim but fixed the CA issues (except for CA1004, this cannot be resolved in this case and is by design)

```
    public static XElement ToXElement<T>(this object value)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
        try
        {
            memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            using (TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
            {
                memoryStream = null;
                var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, value);
                return XElement.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (memoryStream != null)
            {
                memoryStream.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the reason of not wrapping memory stream with using?

Answer (score -2):

What about

```
public static byte[] BinarySerialize(Object obj)
        {
            byte[] serializedObject;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
            try
            {
                b.Serialize(ms, obj);
                ms.Seek(0, 0);
                serializedObject = ms.ToArray();
                ms.Close();
                return serializedObject;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new SerializationException("Failed to serialize. Reason: ");
            }

        }
```

Comment: catch (a real exception) followed by throw some new rubbish exception that has no ability to convey the useful information of the original exception ("Failed to serialize. Reason: ") is terrible.  Just don't catch, or if you want a fake catch for a breakpoint, then simply do "throw;".  Hiding the real exception is bad coding.

Comment: the catch was just an sample!!!, cause main question was about serialize