# how to define the order of array element while serializing xml object in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, xml-serialization

I have this following class.

```
[XmlRoot("MyRoot")]
public class MyRoot
{
    [XmlElement("Node1")]
    public Node1[] Node1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Node2")]
    public Node2[] Node2 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Node3")]
    public Node3[] Node3 { get; set; }

}

public class Node1
{
    [XmlElement("Attrib11")]
    public string Attrib11 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Attrib12")]
    public string Attrib12 { get; set; }
}

public class Node2
{
    [XmlElement("Attrib21")]
    public string Attrib21 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Attrib22")]
    public string Attrib22 { get; set; }
}
public class Node3
{
    [XmlElement("Attrib31")]
    public string Attrib31 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Attrib32")]
    public string Attrib32 { get; set; }
}
```

This below code fill data and serialize

```
var abc = new XML834.MyRoot();
abc.Node1 = new XML834.Node1[] { new XML834.Node1() { Attrib11 = "a11", Attrib12 = "b12" }, new XML834.Node1() { Attrib11 = "c11", Attrib12 = "c12" } };
abc.Node2 = new XML834.Node2[] { new XML834.Node2() { Attrib21 = "a21", Attrib22 = "b22" }, new XML834.Node2() { Attrib21 = "c21", Attrib22 = "c22" } };
abc.Node3 = new XML834.Node3[] { new XML834.Node3() { Attrib31 = "a31", Attrib32 = "b32" }, new XML834.Node3() { Attrib31 = "c31", Attrib32 = "c32" } };

string xmlString = null;
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
using (XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XML834.MyRoot));
    xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, abc);
    MemoryStream memoryBaseStream;
    memoryBaseStream = (MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;
    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    xmlString = encoding.GetString(memoryBaseStream.ToArray());
    memoryBaseStream.Dispose();
    xmlTextWriter.Close();
    memoryStream.Close();
    Console.WriteLine(xmlString);
}
```

The output I am getting is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf 8" ?> 
<MyRoot xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema instance">
<Node1>
  <Attrib11>a11</Attrib11> 
  <Attrib12>b12</Attrib12> 
</Node1>
<Node1>
  <Attrib11>c11</Attrib11> 
  <Attrib12>c12</Attrib12> 
</Node1>
<Node2>
  <Attrib21>a21</Attrib21> 
  <Attrib22>b22</Attrib22> 
</Node2>
<Node2>
  <Attrib21>c21</Attrib21> 
  <Attrib22>c22</Attrib22> 
</Node2>
<Node3>
  <Attrib31>a31</Attrib31> 
  <Attrib32>b32</Attrib32> 
</Node3>
<Node3>
  <Attrib31>c31</Attrib31> 
  <Attrib32>c32</Attrib32> 
</Node3>
</MyRoot>
```

I am trying to specify the order of array item. Is it possible to get this output?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf 8" ?> 
<MyRoot xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema instance">
<Node1>
  <Attrib11>a11</Attrib11> 
  <Attrib12>b12</Attrib12> 
</Node1>
<Node2>
  <Attrib21>a21</Attrib21> 
  <Attrib22>b22</Attrib22> 
</Node2>
<Node3>
  <Attrib31>c31</Attrib31> 
  <Attrib32>c32</Attrib32> 
</Node3>
<Node1>
  <Attrib11>c11</Attrib11> 
  <Attrib12>c12</Attrib12> 
</Node1>
<Node2>
  <Attrib21>c21</Attrib21> 
  <Attrib22>c22</Attrib22> 
</Node2>
<Node3>
  <Attrib31>a31</Attrib31> 
  <Attrib32>b32</Attrib32> 
</Node3>
</MyRoot>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using xelement and customize your serialization like this

```
public class Wrapper
{
    [XmlElement("Node1")]
    public Node1 Node1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Node2")]
    public Node2 Node2 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Node3")]
    public Node3 Node3 { get; set; }
}


[XmlRoot("MyRoot")]
public class MyRoot
{
          private List<Wrapper> _wrappers;

          public MyRoot() { _wrappers = new List<Wrapper>(); }

   public List<Wrapper> Wrappers
   {
          get { return _wrappers; }
          set { _wrappers = value; }
   }

   public string Serialize()
   {
       if (_wrappers.Any())
       {
           XElement inner = new XElement("MyRoot");
           foreach (var w in _wrappers)
           {

               if (w.Node1 != null)
                   inner.Add(  w.Node1.ToXElement<Node1>() ); 
               if (w.Node2 != null)
                   inner.Add(  w.Node2.ToXElement<Node2>() );
               if (w.Node3 != null)
                   inner.Add( w.Node3.ToXElement<Node3>() );
           }
           return inner.ToString();
       }
       return string.Empty;
   }
}
```

ToXElement is an extension that I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373552/serialize-an-object-to-xelement-and-deserialize-it-in-memory) 
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, looks like this is going to work. Let me try and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

You need a different class structure. Something more like this:

```
[XmlRoot("MyRoot")]
public class MyRoot
{
    public MyNode[] MyNodes {get;set;}
}

public class MyNode
{
    [XmlElement("Node1")]
    public Node1 Node1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Node2")]
    public Node2 Node2 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Node3")]
    public Node3 Node3 { get; set; }
}
```

Now, that will get you the correct order, but will also give you an extra element around your "nodes". I don't recall offhand how to get rid of that. Try `[XmlText]` or `[XmlElement]` on the `MyNodes` property.

Comment: This is even a nicer solution, this way you don't use an array but just singular nodes!

Comment: Thank you John, I will try this path. I don't need these wrapped up with MyNode (extra element)

Comment: No it didn't work, xmltext threw exception, xmlelement does include the MyNode wrapper, I tried couple other things like xmlignore which didn't populate any node1,node2... It would be great if you could help me how to get rid of wrapper node

Comment: Ok, just to be clear, you tried `[XmlElement] public MyNode[] MyNodes {get;set;}` and that gave you the extra `<MyNodes>` wrapper? My last thing to try off the top of my head is to use `[XmlArray]`. If that doesn't work, then I'll have to wait until I get home to try.

Comment: Are you required to use the XML Serializer? Because it might be simpler to do this with LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, some detailed information on how to set the order for attributes;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.order(v=vs.110).aspx

For example:

```
[XmlElement(Order = 11)]
public string Attrib11 { get; set; }
```

@Edit 21:10 - 10-09-2014

If you do the following to sort the node:

```
[XmlElement(Order = 1)]
public class Node1{
    [XmlElement("Attrib11")]
    public string Attrib11 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Attrib12")]
    public string Attrib12 { get; set; }
}
```

@edit 21:17 
If you try something like this:

```
int maxLength = Math.Max(node1.length, node2.length, node3.length);
for(int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++){
serialize node1[i];
serialize node2[i];
serialize node3[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this will order the node array group to be ordered but not specific node. Sorry I can't paste the xml output here. Node1,Node2,Node3 order is required to be ordered not the attrib11

Comment: Thank you for your edit 21:10 - 10-09-2014. It doesn't solve my problem. When I specify order at node1,node2,node3 then it change the whole group not one specific node. Please compare expected vs actual output

Comment: When I look closely to your code, I see that you make an array of nodes. So node1 has two nodes. node2 has two nodes and node3 has two nodes. If you want the order to be serialized as in node1 --> node2 --> node3 it makes sense that it will print both node1 than both node2 than both node3.