# 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I try to parse the XML of the following website: [PubMed](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=LCS)

I'm using the following code to do the job:

```
public void SearchByURI(string keyword)
{
    string URI = "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=" + keyword;
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer reader = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(eSearchResult));
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(URI);
    eSearchResult result = new eSearchResult();
    result = (eSearchResult)reader.Deserialize(xmlReader);
}
```

But when I run the code, it crashes at the last line with the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: There is an error in XML document (0, 0).

The class that the XML is supposed to be serialized to can be found at the following pastbin, a bit to large to be pasted in here. [PasteBin link.](http://pastebin.com/PjjpFDTm) This code has been generated by Visual Studio

Comment: The XML serializer is quite a beast, and getting it to interoperate with DTDs can be very involved indeed. Although this is not a direct answer to your question, you may want to consider loading your data into an `XElement` instead and taking that apart yourself. Although it's more code, it's also much easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

So what I did to solve the following problem was to use XElement as suggestet by Jeroen Mostert.

First of all I created to extension methods as suggested in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373552/serialize-an-object-to-xelement-and-deserialize-it-in-memory) like this:

```
public static XElement ToXElement<T>(this object obj)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
            {
                var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, obj);
                return XElement.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()));
            }
        }
    }

    public static T FromXElement<T>(this XElement xElement)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xElement.ToString())))
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);
        }
    }
```

Then i changed the code above to the follwoing:

```
 public eSearchResult SearchByURI(string keyword)
    {
        string URI = "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&term=" + keyword;
        XElement xml = XElement.Load(URI);
        eSearchResult pubMedResult = xml.FromXElement<eSearchResult>();
        return pubMedResult; 
    }
```

Comment: That's... not exactly what I had in mind, I was thinking of writing the code to turn an `XElement` into an `eSearchResult` manually. What happens here is that we first parse the XML using `XElement`, then make it a string again, then parse it again using the `XmlSerializer`! But if that works, then that means parsing it directly with `XmlSerializer` should work as well, and there's just some other subtle issue going on that causes the serializer to fail when reading directly from the URI. That bears further investigation.

Comment: Regardless of the appropriateness of the solution, using `Encoding.ASCII` for the serialization is a bad idea since it doesn't cover the full range of Unicode. `Encoding.UTF8` is a better idea.

Comment: Okay thanks again, i misunderstod you. I will try your method later. :)