# Is there a way to replace whole XML node at once?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I need to replace a list of products (UserCart) with updated list of products for specified user. How can I do that without calling each property?

```
<Users>
<UserInfo>
  <Name>ddd</Name>
  <Wallet>0</Wallet>
  <UserCart>
    <Products_>
      <MedicineProduct
        Product_Name="sak"
        Product_ID="0"
        Price="0"
        Quntity="0"
        Image="" />
    </Products_>
  </UserCart>
</UserInfo>
```

Here's where I stuck...

```
public static void Edit(UserInfo user, Products usercart)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(path);
    XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//UserInfo[./Name/text()='{0}']", user.Name));
}
```

Found specified user. How do I replace whole UserCart node with new value?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the newer `XDocument` API to work with XML and its  [`XElement.ReplaceWith()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.replacewith.aspx) method.

```
var xml = "<Users><UserInfo><Name>Old Name</Name></UserInfo></Users>";
var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var replacedNode = document.Descendants("UserInfo")
                           .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Descendants("Name")
                                                  .Single()
                                                  .Value == "Old Name");

// The code below uses C# 6.0 null propagation feature to handle 
// the case when replacedNode is null (not found in XML).
// In case you use C# 5.x or lower, you can just check it in an IF statement
replacedNode?.ReplaceWith(new XElement("UserInfo", 
                                       new XElement("Name", "New Name")));

Console.WriteLine(document.ToString());
```

**UPDATE (01/14/2016)**

Below is a quick sample on how you can write an extension method to replace user's cart. While this is definitely possible to do, I would avoid mixing business logic (user cart updates) and infrastructure/data tier (serialization) like that. I would rather see user object being de-serialized from XML, updated, and then serialized back.

```
public static class XmlExtensions
{
    public static XElement ToXElement(this object obj)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
            {
                var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, obj);
                return XElement.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()));
            }
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xml = "<Users><UserInfo><Name>Old Name</Name><UserCart></UserCart></UserInfo></Users>";

        var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        var userCart = document.Descendants("UserInfo")
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Descendants("Name").Single().Value == "Old Name")
            ?.Element("UserCart");

        var newUserCart = new UserCart
        {
            Products = new List<Product>
            {
                new Product { Name = "First" },
                new Product { Name = "Second" }
            }
        };

        userCart?.ReplaceWith(newUserCart.ToXElement());

        Console.WriteLine(document.ToString());
    }
}

public class UserCart
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; } 
}

public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

As I mentioned in comments, you can also use attributes from `System.Xml` namespace (e.g. `XmlElement`) to control serialization. Please note thought, that `XmlSerializer` has its limitations. For example, it can't serialize interfaces out of box.

Comment: Note that `?.` (Null conditional operator) is part of C# 6.0, so if OP is using VS 2013 or earlier that operator will not be available.

Comment: You are correct. If you use C# 5.x or lower, you can just check `replacedNode` for `null` instead. Updated the answer.

Comment: I want to replace the whole UserCart with new values lets say with <Products_>
      <MedicineProduct
        Product_Name="new"
        Product_ID="1"
        Price="1"
        Quntity="1"
        Image="" />
    </Products_> Is there a way to do it by simply passing UserCart object - new XElement("UserCart", usercart)))? Or I need to set value to each property of UserCart like Product_Name = " New" etc?

Comment: I think if you pass your object (`userCart`) as `content` to `XElement` constructor, then it will just call `ToString()` on it. I would go with the option described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373552/serialize-an-object-to-xelement-and-deserialize-it-in-memory). That is creating extension methods that use `XmlSerializer` to serialize object. In this case, you will also be able to use attributes from `System.Xml` namespace (`XmlElement`, etc.) to control serialization.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on what you want to replace it with.  If you just want to set some text in there, it's pretty simple:

```
XmlNode cart = doc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//UserInfo[./Name/text()='{0}']/UserCart", "ddd"));
cart.InnerText = "Replaced!";
```

Note I changed your selector so you'd get the actual cart node instead of its parent.

If you want to replace it with new XML nodes, you have to create them, add them to the document, and append them:

```
XmlNode cart = doc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//UserInfo[./Name/text()='{0}']/UserCart", "ddd"));
 // clear out nodes
cart.RemoveAll();
cart.AppendChild(doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "test", ""));
```

With all that said, it's generally best to use the newer `XDocument` API, which might look like...

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
//doc.LoadXml(xml);

XElement cart = doc.Root.Descendants("UserCart").Where(x => (string)x.Parent.Element("Name") == "ddd").FirstOrDefault();
if (cart != null)
    cart.ReplaceNodes(new XElement("test")); // or you can do cart.Value = "text" you're not adding new elements.
```