# c# parse string to xml using StringReader

Tags: c#, xml, class, stringreader

I have an `XML` and I load it in an `class`.

This is my `XML`

```html
<out_policySystem xmlns:msl="http://www.ibm.com/xmlmap" xmlns:io="" xmlns:xs4xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <BGBAResultadoOperacion>
    <Severidad>OK</Severidad>
  </BGBAResultadoOperacion>
  <permiteOperar>true</permiteOperar>
  <Lista xmlns:ns0=\"http://CalypsoPolicySystem_lib/service\">
    <Codigo>ODM-006</Codigo>
    <Descripcion>Aviso</Descripcion>
    <DescripcionTecnica>XXXX</DescripcionTecnica>
  </Lista>
</out_policySystem>
```

I have define my classes like this.

```html
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "out_policySystem")]
    public partial class output_policySystem
    {
        public BGBAResultadoOperacion BGBAResultadoOperacion { get; set; }
        public bool permiteOperar { get; set; }
       public List[] Lista { get; set; }
    }
      public partial class BGBAResultadoOperacion
    {
        public string Severidad { get; set; }
    }
     public partial class List
    {
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public string DescripcionTecnica { get; set; }
    }
```

I read this like this.

```html
 XmlNodeList elemlist = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("out_policySystem");
 string result = elemlist[0].InnerXml;
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BGBAResultadoOperacion));

 using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(result))
 {
 result = (BGBAResultadoOperacion)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
 }
```

the value of `result` is this.

```
<BGBAResultadoOperacion><Severidad>OK</Severidad></BGBAResultadoOperacion><permiteOperar>true</permiteOperar><Lista><Codigo>ODM-006</Codigo><Descripcion>Aviso</Descripcion><DescripcionTecnica>xxxx</DescripcionTecnica></Lista>
```

What I need is to get the value of BGBAResultadoOperacion

when i set

```
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(result))
     {
     result = (BGBAResultadoOperacion)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
     }
```

result get XML error...

```
There are multiple root elements. Line 1, position 76.
```

XML node out_`policySystem` has three root elements inside it. I need to parse only `BGBAResultadoOperacion`

How can I get it?

Thanks

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: I add inner exception... it says There are multiple root elements. Line 1, position 76. thanks

Comment: You need to read the entire xml.  The xml serialize needs a well formed xml file which means you can only have one root element.   You are removing the element out_policySystem which is the cause of the error which then gives three elements at the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of this line:

```
elemlist[0].InnerXml
```

Which returns an XML Fragment, not an XML Document.

```
  <BGBAResultadoOperacion>
    <Severidad>OK</Severidad>
  </BGBAResultadoOperacion>
  <permiteOperar>true</permiteOperar>
  <Lista xmlns:ns0=\"http://CalypsoPolicySystem_lib/service\">
    <Codigo>ODM-006</Codigo>
    <Descripcion>Aviso</Descripcion>
    <DescripcionTecnica>XXXX</DescripcionTecnica>
  </Lista>
```

So either use the .OuterXML, or use XElement.CreateReader() as described in the answer here: [Serialize an object to XElement and Deserialize it in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373552/serialize-an-object-to-xelement-and-deserialize-it-in-memory)